# Fill in a select box automatically with the value same as user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I'm trying to fill a select list with the values entered in an input text box when the user clicks on a button. For eg:

HTML:

```
<form>
                <h2>Add EVENT/MARKET/SELECTION ID </h2>
                <select id="id_type">
                        <option value="sEVENT">Event</option>
                        <option value="sEVMKT">Market</option>
                        <option value="sSELCN">Selection</option>
                 </select>

                <input id="entered_id" type="number"/>

              <button id="add_id" onclick="populateList()">Add</button>
</form>
<form>
                <h2>Entered IDs</h2>
                <select id="list_id" size="10" multiple="true"></select>

</form>
```

JS:

```
function populateList() {
        var events_id   = document.getElementById('entered_id').value;  
/*I want this events_id to be entered to the select list "list_id"*/
}
```

I tried $("#list_id").append(events_id) but that didn't work.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since its `<select>` you need to append `<option>` tag, as:

```
$("#list_id").append("<option value='"+events_id+"'>"+events_id+"</option>");
```

Comment: For some reason, the value appears in the select list for a fraction of a second and then disappears. I shall debug it. In the meantime, if you know what could be wrong, please let me know.

Comment: Well, it was because my select lists were enclosed in "form"s. It worked fine when I removed the form tag. But what if I want to have it in a form tag??

Answer (score 1):

Try **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j9x9n20b/1/)**

```
 $("#add_id").click(function () {
      var value = $("#entered_id").val();    
      $("#list_id").append("<option value =" + value + " >" + value + "</option>");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

using JavaScript

```
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.text = document.getElementById('entered_id').value;  
option.value = document.getElementById('entered_id').value;  
var select = document.getElementById("list_id");
select.appendChild(option);
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing everything the jQuery way you can bind a click handler to the button instead of the inline method.

```
$('#add_id').click(function() {
  $('<option/>', { text: this.value }).appendTo('#list_id');
});
```